# Default precision scale data type in snowflake

Tags: jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I want to create a table with column as decimal and I dont want to specify any precision scale, it seems using number as dataType it create column as Number(38,0) by default.
How can I get some default value for scale as well.
In other db like oracle numeric takes default scale and we are able to insert decimal values but the same is not happening in snowflake

Answer (score 1):

You are right that it is defined as NUMBER(38,0) when you don't specify a scale. It's a popular request from Snowflake users, and there is already a project to improve the NUMBER data type. Unfortunately, there is no ETA yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table with data type FLOAT/DECIMAL/DOUBLE etc, all these data types use underlying precision/scale = 15/9. It actually uses double data type internally.

You can try like
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE table_double (
Scale REAL
);

```
insert into table_double values 
(103269015259.46179);
insert into table_double values 
(10326901.461);
```

It will truncate after 15/9.

Please refer to the documentation.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-numeric.html#data-types-for-floating-point-numbers

Regards,
Sujan